# iOS 8.3 breaks automatic cell height

Tags: ios, ios8, ios8.3

Long time reader, first time poster.

I use automatic cell height with auto layout in my app. In iOS 8.3 and 8.4, this appears to be broken. I have a sample project. When built in 8.2 or lower, it works properly. The cell heights are determined by Autolayout. When built in 8.3 or 8.4 it doesn't work. I have searched online and I don't see anyone posting about this issue.

Take a look at the screenshots below. Any help is appreciated.

[Cell Height Project ZIP](http://jeffburg.com/skitch/CellHeightProject.zip)

[Screenshot comparison http://jeffburg.com/skitch/CellHeightProjectComparison.png](http://jeffburg.com/skitch/CellHeightProjectComparison.png)

Thanks!
-Jeff

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/a/29583343/2442804 maybe help you!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked your code and found the problem.

Reading through AppCodas [article](http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/) about self-sizing cells, it looks like you should use `estimatedRowHeight` when using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` (haven't used it myself, cannot confirm). So either remove the following line:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

or add (if your cell height will be changing based on content):

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 122;
```

Comment: Per Gasim you missed the `estimatedRowHeight` and this is required along with setting the `rowHeight` to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` in order to correctly use self sizing table views.

Comment: I tried uprooting the replies but I don't have enough reputation yet :-/

Comment: Thanks a lot for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have the same issue on my iOS >8.3 project. I fixed your [sample](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11303853/variableheightrows.zip) project by implementing the delegate methods instead of setting the rowHeight in viewDidLoad. This is definitely a bug related to UITableView, so you did nothing wrong.

Comment: I forgot to mention that it's always good to provide an estimatedRowHeight. In your case I just reference to the cellHeight from the Storyboard.

Comment: wow. how embarrassing. What an easy fix. Thanks a lot! I tried uprooting the replies but I don't have enough reputation yet :-/

Answer (score 0):

Add this method on your delegate:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```